# Javascript access array of objects by value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that contains value pairs. I want to be able to access a value like this

```
myArray.code 
or
myArray[0].code
```

but it says myArray does not contain code.
In the console this is what my array looks like. As you can see each object has two items in it and I want to access code and name by them selves not together and I dont know how to do this.

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {code: "PROG2700", name: "Client Side Programming"}
1: {code: "PROG1400", name: "jk"}
length: 2
```

this is the initial array holding these objects

```
 let [state_array_items, setState_array_items] = React.useState<Object[]>([]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type of `Object[]` is took generic, so the Typescript compiler is throwing a fit. If you know that your type will always be `{ code: string; name: string }[]`, you should specify that and TS will be happy.

```js
type SomeObject = { code: string; name: string };

let [state_array_items, setState_array_items] = React.useState<SomeObject[]>([]);
```

[Here's a TS playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFAWBLMBzAXDA8gIwFYFNgoBtAXRgF4YyBuAKDoWRWIAZSA6UAE3wdEiwQCfACcAKklQYA3jB74M0UcxowwAQwC2imMuYwAvmUrVS9OsPhjJzNpwVA) of the TS compiler complaining when you just use `Object[]` but being okay when the type you provide is more specific:

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I made an interface in my model that handled this so I can use it for other components, thanks